# AttributeError: 'LoginViewModel' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, flask, attributeerror

In my flask application, i want to call attribute from parent class, but each time  AttributeError exception is occuring, i do not know why it is happening. i'm currently using python 3.9.9 in my linux enviroment and pyenv.

```
class ViewModelBase:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "expense_tracker"
        self.user_id: Optional[str] = current_user.get_id()
        self.request: Request = flask.request
        self.request_dict = request_dict.create('')
        self.success: str

    def to_dict(self):
        return self.__dict__


class ViewModelBaseUser(ViewModelBase):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_name = self.request_dict.user_name.strip()
        self.email = self.request_dict.email.lower().strip()
        self.first_name = self.request_dict.first_name.strip()
        self.second_name = self.request_dict.second_name.strip()
        self.country = self.request_dict.country
        self.countries = country_service.all_countries()


class LoginViewModel(ViewModelBase, ViewModelDataValidator):
  
  def __init__(self):
    super(ViewModelDataValidator, self).__init__()
    super(ViewModelBase, self).__init__()
    
    self.login = self.request_dict.login.lower().strip()
    self.password = self.request_dict.password.strip()

    self.remember_login = self.request_dict.remember_login == 'on'

  def validate(self):
    if not self.login:
        self.error.append(gettext(""))
    if not self.password:
        self.error.append(gettext(""))

 def value_name(self):
     return self.name
```

Answer (score -1):

ok... i found the problem, even if i called super for init from both parent classes only one super().**init**() was required and everything is working fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).